# TStringGrid with BOTH editing AND range selection?

Tags: delphi, vcl, tstringgrid

Question:

Can anyone point to an article or code samples anywhere on how to 
provide BOTH editing AND range selection in a TStringGrid?

Yes, I KNOW there are third-party grids that do this, but it's 
frustrating that the built-in grid lacks this basic capability.

Background:

It's pretty normal to expect to be able to both edit a cell in a grid, 
and also to select a range of cells such as for a Copy operation.

As delivered, TStringGrid doesn't do that. It's either/or.  In fact, the 
docs tell us about the grid Options, "When goEditing is included in 
Options, goRangeSelect has no effect".

However, it looks like it may be possible to do editing and rangeselects 
in a TStringGrid anyway!!!  Through careful use of the mousedown, 
mouseup, selectcell and exit events, you can get dang close by switching 
editing elements on and off at the right times.  But I still don't have 
it perfect, and that only covers mouse use, not keyboard changes.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used the `TStringGrid` for this, so I can't provide a specific answer.  But am I right in assuming you can [manually (in code) start a cell being edited](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Grids.TCustomGrid.ShowEditor)?  That link implies it is possible even if the grid doesn't have `goEditing` included in its `Options`.  (See below to work around this if this is not true.)

If so, I'd suggest the following approach:

### Combined selection and edit behaviour

I find this is a good, Windows-standard-behaviour sort of approach:

- Leave the grid in selection mode, so mouse and keyboard interaction selects cells
- Trigger a cell being edited yourself, based on certain criteria (I think you are on the way to doing this from what you said in your last paragraph.)  There are common ways to trigger editing, and the following criteria are what my programs follow when they do something similar with other controls:

  - Selection is normal.  Ie, click to select, click and drag to multi-select, use the keyboard arrows and Shift or Control to select, etc.
  - A cell [enters edit mode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Grids.TCustomGrid.ShowEditor) when either:

    1. A cell is selected and the user presses `Enter` or `F2` (`F2` is the standard "Rename" or "Edit" shortcut, which works in a number of programs)
    2. The user "slow-double-clicks" on a cell - ie, slow-double-clicks to select and edit, or clicks again, after a pause, on an already-selected cell.  This mimics Explorer's behaviour, where if a file is selected and you later click on it, it enters the inline edit/rename mode.  To implement this, record when a cell was last clicked (and selected.)  If it is clicked again, and if the time is greater than [`GetDoubleClickTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646258%28VS.85%29.aspx) then they have clicked twice, slowly, and enter edit mode.  This allows you to distinguish between the first click to select, a double-click (to perform some kind of action), and a slow second click, to enter edit mode.

       I also tend to check the mouse position, so that if an object is slow-double-clicked and it wasn't first selected (ie, this both selects the object and then enters edit mode) I verify the mouse hasn't moved very much.  I use [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the double-click distance, and check that the slow double click was within this box.  (Because it's not a true doubleclick, I actually check the distance times 2.  My action code is:

       `const int iMAX_MOVE_AMOUNT = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDOUBLECLK) * 2;` (sorry, C++ not Delphi, but should be convertable easily enough!)

       but I'm actually not certain if this is completely and utterly 100% to Windows guidelines.  In practice users find it works as they expect, though.)

That should let you change between selecting and editing at the appropriate times with both the keyboard and the mouse.

### Miscellaneous thoughts

You may find some of this is cleaner and easier to implement by subclassing `TStringGrid` and creating a new component.  That will allow you to implement this in normal code and override the inbuilt behaviour (rather than event handlers) while keeping it invisible to the form code.  It will also give you lower-level access to the mouse events or Windows messages than are exposed simply through events such as `OnMouseDown`.  Finally, if there are problems with showing the editor when `goEditing` is included in `Options`, this will allow you to change that behaviour.  You could also add your own events if you want your code to respond to certain things happening, such as creating an `OnBeginEdit` event, say.

Creating your own components is normally regarded as an advanced Delphi topic, but it's actually *remarkably easy once you know how!*  [This site](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/customvcldev.htm) has a few good topics that will introduce you to the subject in general, and if you go this route and encounter problems, Stack Overflow is of course a good place to ask questions :)  The Embarcadero [Delphi  » VCL  » Writing Components](https://forums.codegear.com/forum.jspa?forumID=96) newsgroup / forum is also an excellent resource, in fact possibly even better than SO for this specific topic.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's old post, but the problem still exist on Delphi XE3. 
To manage this feature I used next "trick" in SelectCell procedure :

`if (ARow = StringGridParam.Row) then
begin
    StringGridParam.Options:= StringGridParam.Options + [goEditing] - [goRowSelect];
end else begin
    StringGridParam.Options:= StringGridParam.Options + [goRowSelect] - [goEditing];
end;`

Comment: Works better if you add the exact code to the OnCellClick event.